# Why do Modelica.Fluid-pipes fail to work with my medium?

Tags: modelica

I built a medium model based on Modelica.Media to simulate a phase change slurry. The model works fine for investigations of static problems (medium at rest). But if I try to conduct my medium through a standard pipe from Modelica.Fluid, things won't work.

I put a demo Modelica package on DropBox - if anyone could have a look on it, I would be deeply grateful.
Find my PCS-Package under http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28688128/PCS.mo

The package contains the medium model as well as three test models:

- *EmptyTanks0* shows two balancing tanks connected directly to one another.
- *EmptyTanks1* shows the same set-up, but with a StaticPipe connecting the tanks. In this case, no medium is conducted. Why?
- The last set-up is called *EmptyTanks2*. This one uses a DynamicPipe instead of the StaticPipe. The model fails at initialisation. Why?

Comment: FYI, the DropBox link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

The Dynamic pipe assumes a compressible medium (meaning, the properties have to depend on the fact that pressure p is a dynamic state (or other states, but some equivalent transformation such that density d is a function of p also, not only of T and composition X as for you. The pipe model will not work if that is not fulfilled, and you get a division by zero from that inconsistency.

Your medium model looks OK at first look (I didn't do deeper digging), but you will have to write your own pipe model. One tip: writing it is*much, much* simpler than the dynamic pipe model in the MSL.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your help. At least you confirmed what I was already suspecting - that I have to write my own pipe model. So I can focus on a new pipe model and stop thinking about what causes the standard pipe not to work with my medium.

Best regards, TIMO.

Comment: Huh, it would be really useful if the documentation of the DynamicPipe would tell you that it only works with compressible media. Also, curiously, there are examples in the Fluid library where DynamicPipes are used with incompressible media (e.g. `IncompressibleFluidNetwork`), so no idea what's going on there.